# How to switch php versions on Manjaro Linux

Tags: php, linux, terminal, manjaro

Is it possible to quickly switches between a few php versions (eg. 5.6, 7.4, 8) on manjaro linux without using a docker?

For small web projects.

Comment: https://github.com/phpbrew/phpbrew perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

What’s the output of:

```
alias php
```

If the ‘alias’ command didn't generate any output. It assign the left term to the right.

It means when you run

```
alias php=/usr/bin/php7
```

you then can run `/usr/bin/php7` by typing ‘php’ in your console.
This is not permanent, after a reboot this ‘alias’ is gone. If you want this permanent you have to write the ‘alias’ in this file: ~/.bashrc

I would suggest to alias the older to an extra name like php7:

```
alias php7=/usr/bin/php7
```

So you can run your scripts with both versions:

```
php your-script.php
```

runs your script with actual php version, and

```
php7 your-script.php
```

runs your script with php7.

Reference: https://forum.manjaro.org/t/switch-php-versions-on-manjaro/59957